# Show one i frame, hide another using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

If a user already has one video selected (using the drop-down), and they select another, I would like the first video to be replaced with the new video. Instead, how I have it set up right now, it is just appending the second video (or even third, if a third video is selected) after the first. How do I change my code to clear any current videos from the page before loading the new video?

```
<body>
  <h1>Let's Meditate.</h1>
  <select id="timer">
    <option value="select" disabled selected>Select One...</option>
    <option value="twenty">20 minutes</option>
    <option value="fifteen">15 minutes</option>
    <option value="ten">10 minutes</option>
    <option value="five">5 minutes</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="meditate();">Go!</button>
  <button onclick="refresh();">Refresh</button>
  <div class="videos">
    <iframe id="twentyMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VjxGjDo1tWA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="fifteenMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aIIEI33EUqI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="tenMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xl_B45DpMLU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="fiveMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3RxXiFgkxGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>

    function meditate() {
      var timer = document.getElementById("timer").value;

      if(timer == "twenty") {
        document.getElementById("twentyMinVid").style.display = "block";
      } else if(timer == "fifteen") {
        document.getElementById("fifteenMinVid").style.display = "block";
      } else if(timer == "ten") {
        document.getElementById("tenMinVid").style.display = "block";
      } else if(timer == "five") {
        document.getElementById("fiveMinVid").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".videos").innerHTML = "Please select a time limit and click Go."
      }
    }

    function refresh() {
      location.reload();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not hiding the existing iframes when you display the new one.

For example, in this block:

```
if(timer == "twenty") {
    document.getElementById("twentyMinVid").style.display = "block";

    //Add code here for hiding the other divs
     document.getElementById("fifteenMinVid").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("tenMinVid").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("fiveMinVid").style.display = "none";
  }
....You need to do this same thing in other sections so that you are hiding other divs while you show the correct div.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making there `display: block`, try changing the iframe src.

```
 <body>
 <h1>Let's Meditate.</h1>
 <select id="timer">
<option value="select" disabled selected>Select One...</option>
<option value="twenty">20 minutes</option>
<option value="fifteen">15 minutes</option>
<option value="ten">10 minutes</option>
<option value="five">5 minutes</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="meditate();">Go!</button>
 <button onclick="refresh();">Refresh</button>
 <div class="videos">
 <iframe id="iframe" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<script>

 function meditate() {
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer").value;
  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

  if(timer == "twenty") {
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VjxGjDo1tWA";
  } else if(timer == "fifteen") {
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/aIIEI33EUqI";
  } else if(timer == "ten") {
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xl_B45DpMLU";
  } else if(timer == "five") {
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/3RxXiFgkxGc";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".videos").innerHTML = "Please select a time limit and click Go."
    }
  }

  function refresh() {
      location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution I modified your code a bit.

```
<body>
  <h1>Let's Meditate.</h1>
  <select id="timer">
    <option value="select" disabled selected>Select One...</option>
    <option value="twentyMinVid">20 minutes</option>
    <option value="fifteenMinVid">15 minutes</option>
    <option value="tenMinVid">10 minutes</option>
    <option value="fiveMinVid">5 minutes</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="meditate();">Go!</button>
  <button onclick="refresh();">Refresh</button>
  <div class="videos">
    <iframe id="twentyMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VjxGjDo1tWA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="fifteenMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aIIEI33EUqI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="tenMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xl_B45DpMLU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe id="fiveMinVid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3RxXiFgkxGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
  function meditate() {
   var timer = document.getElementById("timer").value;
   if (timer === 'select') {
     alert("Please select a time limit and click Go.");
     return;
   }
   var options = document.getElementById("timer").options;
   for (var i = 1; i < options.length; i++) {
     if (options[i].value === timer) {
       document.getElementById(timer).style.display = "block";
     } else {
       document.getElementById(options[i].value).style.display = "none";
     }
   }

 }

 function refresh() {
   location.reload();
 }

  </script>
</body>
```

I tried to make it more generic so that if you add more option in dropdown then if dropdown value is same as frameId then no modification is needed in the logic to show/hide videos

link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qecpxw4f/)